# TypeError: '<' not supportef of 'list' in Python

Tags: list, integer, typeerror

Here is a copy of my code:

```
scores = [100, 90, 80]
par_info = []
    
for i in scores:
    if scores == 80:
        par_info = "Made Par"
    elif scores < 80:
        par_info = "Under Par"
    elif scores > 80:
        par_info = "Over Par"
```

I understand that the loop does not go over a list but I cannot find the answer to solve this whatsoever. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are comparing your array `scores` with the number 80:

```
if scores == 80:
```

You can't compare an array with a number, what you are probably trying to do is comparing the current element of the loop `i` with the number:

```
scores = [100, 90, 80]
par_info = []
    
for i in scores:
    if i == 80:
        par_info = "Made Par"
    elif i < 80:
        par_info = "Under Par"
    elif i > 80:
        par_info = "Over Par"
```

You probably also want to be appending to the array:

```
scores = [100, 90, 80]
par_info = []
    
for i in scores:
    if i == 80:
        par_info.append("Made Par")
    elif i < 80:
        par_info.append("Under Par")
    elif i > 80:
        par_info.append("Over Par")
```